# Can't use mysqli_fetch_array for two different columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a small code that displays data from the database.:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$checkuserlogin='SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname="raj"';
$runcheckuserlogin=mysqli_query($connect,$checkuserlogin);
echo mysqli_fetch_array($runcheckuserlogin)['ts'];
echo mysqli_fetch_array($runcheckuserlogin)['llogin'];
?>
```

This only gives me the value in 'ts' column. If i reorder the echo lines, I get the one that appears first. and the second echo line doesn't return anything.

I must be doing something wrong... because i didn't get anyone facing same issue here...

Comment: Read the DOCS for `mysqli_fetch_array`. The answer is there.

Comment: Kindly can u just tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvoting? I don't see anything wrong with the question

Comment: @AbhishekRaj You are doing it wrong way. Go through the DOCS there you will get all the explanation step by step.

Comment: @b0s3: I think OP knows they are doing wrong, hence the question. Your comments are useless, you can't even be bothered to provide a link to the 'DOCS'. I wonder did you get your rep from posting answers to people just telling them they are doing it wrong and they should go away and learn how to do it properly?

Comment: @musefan I dont see anything wrong with that. Every1 **should learn first**, **try on their own**, if not working then **search first** for the solution, after doing all if it is not solved then there is **SO**. I think these problem would easily resolved if OP check the documentation once.

Comment: @b0s3: SO is not exclusively for questions that have never been answered anywhere else on the internet before. If you can find an SO duplicate then fair enough, vote to close as dupe. But you shouldn't judge questions on how easy they are (for you) to solve. OP has shown attempts, so it's not like they haven't tried something.

Comment: People,... I'm a new learner and did use mysql_fetch_array the wrong way for so many days... It was giving me the results, so worked for me.. Anyway I get it now.

Comment: That's why @AbhishekRaj I was suggesting you to go through the documentations so that you can avoid this issues.

Comment: @b0s3 I completely understand... Will do it next time i face an issue

Answer (score 2):

Dont execute mysqli_fetch_array twice:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $runcheckuserlogin);
echo $row['ts'];
echo $row['llogin'];
```

For bonus points, you should really be dealing with MySQLi in an object oriented fashion too. See [mysqli::query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for how....

Comment: okay!! thanks.. I'm used to working with mysql...and there it worked fine.. So couldn't realise that it's not supported with mysqli

Comment: @AbhishekRaj Decrepit mysql also does not allow mysql_fetch_array to be used twice. See the [mysql fetch array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: AFAIK, you'd be doing it wrong with the mysql library (which you shouldn't have been using for several years now anyway) too.

Comment: @JamieSterling I dont know, but I just tested using the same way on my xampp and it did give me correct results! with mysql_fetch_array... I dont know how :P It's the wrong way I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you should only use mysqli_fetch_array once per query.

[Here is a link to mysqli_fetch_array documents](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

I've added the correct way to do it.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

$checkuserlogin='SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname="raj"';

$runcheckuserlogin=mysqli_query($connect,$checkuserlogin);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($runcheckuserlogin);
echo $row["ts"];
echo $row["llogin"];

?>
```

Comment: Now I get it! I posted this question because it worked fine with mysql... and they've changed it in mysqli